# Handling keypresses in Psychopy

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm trying to design a behavioral task where I show one baseline picture for 3 seconds, and during this time, if a key `1` is pressed then the picture should be switched with a new picture (associated with the `1` keypress), if `2` is pressed instead then a different picture is presented. 
In addition, I need to have a condition in which no matter what happens (either a keypress happens or not during the 3 seconds of displaying the Baseline picture) then the current routine will end and move to the next routine.

I have no idea how I can execute these specifications in Psychopy.

*I use the Coder (not the Builder interface)

Comment: Could you update your question, stating whether you use Builder or Coder? It sounds like Builder, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: I use the Coder. The Builder doesn't seem powerful enough.

Comment: And yet Builder could handle all of this easily, supplemented by just a couple of lines of custom code in code components. If you wish to code this yourself, then you'll need to create the necessary algorithmic structures yourself. The relevant PsychoPy functions to display stimuli and capture key presses are relatively straightforward, so it's seems that your issue is more one of understanding at the general Python code structure level?

Comment: I have already implemented the display stimuli part in the script, but failed to implement the conditions for the keypresses that I've specified in the questions (both by using the builder or the coder). I can share my script if that will help

Answer (score 0):

"I have no idea how to program my experiment" is not a useful level of question for StackOverflow (nor for the dedicated PsychoPy forum). You'll need to learn enough about the basics to get started (Builder strongly recommended) and then ask a more specific question

Comment: That's also not a very useful reply as well :)

Comment: I have learned Psychopy, and I know the Builder and the Coder, I just specified the specific conditions that I want to implement and that's the only thing that I "have no idea" how to define. I can share my script so far if that helps.